# setup requirement of stereo camera

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

In the stereo camera system, two cameras are needed and should be mounted side by side. I see someone just glues two cameras to a wooden board. However One mobile phone manufacture claimed that the two lens of dual camera modules on their phone are parallel within 0.3 degree. Why do two lens on mobile phones need such high precise assembly? Does this will bring any benefit?

Answer (score 3):

I have not worked on stereo setup, but would like to answer from what I have studied during my course. Camera setup which are not parallel are usually called converged/toe-in setup. 
Stereo camera setup which are parallel does provide some advantages over toe-in setup. But the advantage is not absolute and dependent on what is required.

- In toe-in setup there is a problem of keystoning. Keystoning is when two images(Left and Right) are kept side by side, the images are aligned at the meeting point but they tilt as you go further towards the edge. This leads to depth plane curvature and it shows as though farther objects are curved. This can be corrected in post processing and its called keystone correction. There is no keystone problem in parallel setup. Below image shows image distortion towards edges. If your requirement is not to have keystone effect, then it is an advantage ;)

[image]

- In parallel setup you can decide the image convergence in post processing by slightly shifting the images horizontally(Horizontal image translation HIT). In toe-in you need to decide the convergence area during the shoot. Convergence is the region of the image which is same in both Left and Right. As you can imagine, in parallel setup, there is no convergence and you get stereo effect for the whole image. This is good right ? Depends. Because, in stereo, we have zero place, near plane and far place. Zero plane is when the image is perceived as to be formed on the screen(screen on which image is projected in the theatre).Near field is near the viewer(imagine popping out of the screen towards the viewer). Far field is farther from the viewer. Therefore, since there is no convergence in parallel setup the whole screen has stereo effect(that is near or far field, see figure below) and convergence is at infinity. Now imagine sky which is very deep in real, i.e the sky which is at infinity. But since in parallel setup sky converges as it is at infinity and appears to be formed on the screen. But a person who is near to the viewer seems to be floating in stereo space, which messes up the brain. Therefore usually people prefer slight convergence angle to avoid this or use HIT such that the convergence point appears on the zero field. Hope this helps :) I will try to rephrase this tomorrow as I wrote this in one go.

[image]